# RiscV spec v2.1 Vol 1 User Level ISA duplicate opcodes listing?

Tags: specifications, riscv

I do not consider this a big problem but I found duplicate entries for opcodes "SLLI,SRLI and SRAI" for RV32I and RV64I instruction sets of the user level ISA spec. This contradicts the table header "in addition to RV32I" and looks to be a duplication error. I am referring to the tables in Chapter 9 "RV32/64G Instruction Set Listings" in ["Risc-V Instruction Set Manual/Volume I: User-Level ISA Version 2.1"](https://riscv.org/specifications/) ([pdf](https://content.riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/riscv-spec-v2.1.pdf)) where the intent is to list each opcode only once:

```
RV32I Base Instruction Set
0000000 shamt rs1 001 rd 0010011 SLLI
0000000 shamt rs1 101 rd 0010011 SRLI
0100000 shamt rs1 101 rd 0010011 SRAI
...

RV64I Base Instruction Set (in addition to RV32I)
000000 shamt rs1 001 rd 0010011 SLLI
000000 shamt rs1 101 rd 0010011 SRLI
010000 shamt rs1 101 rd 0010011 SRAI
```

Since I have not seen any replies to this post - is this the correct forum to post these type of minor problems in the RiscV specs?

Comment: Dave, can you add exact URL (web) links to the document (https://content.riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/riscv-spec-v2.1.pdf)? Exact quote of problem? Why do you think about same opcode as a problem/error? (This may be the wrong forum to ask about typos)

Comment: dave, **They are different: 5-bit shamt for 32-bit and 6-bit shamt for 64-bit mode**. Quoting the lines from tables helps to compare them, so, do some amount of editing (add links and quotes) when post questions. Sometimes you will be able to close question before sending to SO.

Comment: osgx you are correct - they differ in the shamt field width. Although they use the same opcode mnemonic. Thanks.  I apologize if I did not state my original post clearly and in the future I will use weblinks to the specs.

Answer (score 1):

"Risc-V Instruction Set Manual/Volume I: User-Level ISA Version 2.1"
https://content.riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/riscv-spec-v2.1.pdf
in Chapter 9 lists (page 64 of pdf, 54 of text):

```
RV32I Base Instruction Set
0000000 shamt rs1 001 rd 0010011 SLLI
0000000 shamt rs1 101 rd 0010011 SRLI
0100000 shamt rs1 101 rd 0010011 SRAI
```

then on next page

```
RV64I Base Instruction Set (in addition to RV32I)
000000 shamt rs1 001 rd 0010011 SLLI
000000 shamt rs1 101 rd 0010011 SRLI
010000 shamt rs1 101 rd 0010011 SRAI
0000000 shamt rs1 001 rd 0011011 SLLIW
0000000 shamt rs1 101 rd 0011011 SRLIW
0100000 shamt rs1 101 rd 0011011 SRAIW
```

At page 38 (pdf) 28 (text) the instructions are defined:

```
31 26 25 24 20 19 15 14 12 11 7 6 0
imm[11:6] imm[5]   imm[4:0]  rs1 funct3 rd  opcode
   6      1         5         5    3    5    7
000000   shamt[5] shamt[4:0] src SLLI  dest OP-IMM
000000   shamt[5] shamt[4:0] src SRLI  dest OP-IMM
010000   shamt[5] shamt[4:0] src SRAI  dest OP-IMM
000000     0      shamt[4:0] src SLLIW dest OP-IMM-32
000000     0      shamt[4:0] src SRLIW dest OP-IMM-32
010000     0      shamt[4:0] src SRAIW dest OP-IMM-32
```

> **SLLI** is a logical left shift (zeros are shifted into the lower bits); **SRLI** is a logical right shift (zeros are shifted into the upper bits); and **SRAI** is an arithmetic right shift (the original sign bit is copied into the vacated upper bits). For RV32I, **SLLI**, **SRLI**, and **SRAI** generate an illegal instruction exception if imm[5] != 0.
>   **SLLIW**, **SRLIW**, and **SRAIW** are RV64I-only instructions that are analogously defined but operate on 32-bit values and produce signed 32-bit results. SLLIW, SRLIW, and SRAIW generate an illegal instruction exception if imm[5] != 0

So, in 32-bit mode and in 64-bit mode SLLI/SRLI/SRAI behaves differently. In 32-bit mode they have 5-bit shamt and in 64-bit they have 6-bit shamt.

> This contradicts

This does not. You just did not count/compare `imm` value in different tables. In one table it is `0000000 shamt` (7 zeroes, 5-bit shamt) and in other it is `000000 shamt` (6 zeroes, 6-bit shamt).

Comment: osgx after you posted your answer - I decided to test my understanding (it appears I am limited on the size of a comment on this forum).  I will post another question.  Please refer to this new question.

Comment: @daveW, if you consider this question closed and answered you may or may not mark this answer as correct by clicking 'v'-shaped button left to it. If you consider this question&answer as not useful at all, you may or may not try to flag it to delete.

Comment: osgx - please see question title "RiscV assembler - experimenting with the 'slli' command for RV32I"

Comment: osgx - after some thought I think the tables starting on page 54 of the spec could use a different format. It is an 'eye-chart' to look at many consecutive 0's and hence I feel this is error prone.  The 'andi' instruction on the next row above 'slli' for the description for 'imm[11:0]' is much easier on my eyes.  How does one submit this suggestion to RiscV?